# Use of Wrapper class for deserialization in callout?

Tags: salesforce, wrapper, apex-code, apex

I found the following use of a wrapper class, and was wondering if it is a good practice or whether its just duplication of code for no reason.

```
    //Class:
    public class SomeClass{
        public Integer someInt;
        public String someString;
    }

    //Callout Class:

    public class CalloutClass{
        public SomeClass someMethod(){
            //...code to do a callout to an api
            SomeClass someClassObj = (SomeClass)JSON.Deserialize(APIResponse.getBody(), SomeClass.class);
            return someClassObj;
        }
    }

    //Controller:

    public class SomeController {
        public SomeController(){
            someClassObj = calloutClassObj.someMethod();
            SomeWrapper wrapperObj = new SomeWrapper();
            for(SomeClass iterObj : someClassObj){
                wrapperObj.someWrapperInt = iterObj.someInt;
                wrapperObj.someWrapperString = iterObj.someString;
            }
        }
        public class someWrapper{
            public Integer someWrapperInt{get;set;}
            public String someWrapperString{get;set;}
        }
    }
```

The wrapper class "someWrapper" could be eliminated if we just use getters and setters ({get;set;}) in "SomeClass."

Could anyone explain if there could be a reason for following this procedure?

Thanks,
James

Answer (score 0):

My assumption (because, code in controller is extra pseudo) is

**SomeClass** is a business entity, purpose of which is to store/work with business data. By work I mean using it's values to display it (using wrapper in controller), to calculate smth in other entities or build reports... Such kind of object should be as lightweight as possible. You usually iterate through them. You don't need any methods in such kind of objects. Exception is constructor with parameter(s). You might want to have *SomeObject__c* as parameter or *someWrapper*.

**someWrapper** is a entity to display business entity. As for wrapper classes in controllers. Imagine, that when you display entity on edit page and enter a value for *someWrapperInt* property, you want to update *someWrapperString* property (or you can just put validation there, for example, checking if it is really Integer). Usually, as for business entity, you don't want such kind of functionality. But when user create or edit it, you may want smth like this.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It does make sense to have a business entity to be as lightweight as possible. However, **SomeClass** is being used just for deserialization on GET, not for serialization on POST. Is it good practice to have the class used for deserialization to be void of methods?

Comment: In your example you use it in a controller. I would think, that it intent is to display data after retrieving in from Web Service.

Comment: It's totally ok and actually very simple. One line and you have your data. You don't need to parse body of Web Service response.